# php getimagesize inside xslt

Tags: php, xslt

I am quite a bit outside of my comfort zone, working with xslt.

I would like to get the positive ratio between the height and width of an image. But I am having trouble even getting the parameters.

I tried this one:

```
<xsl:value-of select="php:functionString('getimagesize', image)"/></xsl:element>
```

But that of course just outputs "Array". 
Is there a way to "break" the array similar to $size[1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a DOMDocument or document fragment in your PHP code which contains the data you want to return, then you can use XPath on the XSLT side to select the data, here is an example:

```
<?php



function getDims($url) {
    $info = getimagesize($url);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $root = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('dimensions'));
    $doc->appendChild($root);
    $width = $doc->createElement('width', $info[0]);
    $root->appendChild($width);
    $height = $doc->createElement('height', $info[1]);
    $root->appendChild($height);
    return $doc;
}


$xml = <<<'EOB'
<root>
  <image>foo.gif</image>
</root>
EOB;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$xsl = <<<'EOB'
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
     xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
     exclude-result-prefixes="exsl php">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>


 <xsl:template match="image">
   <xsl:variable name="dimensions" select="php:function('getDims', string(.))/*"/>
   <img width="{$dimensions/width}" height="{$dimensions/height}" src="{.}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOB;

$xsldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xsldoc->loadXML($xsl);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->registerPHPFunctions();

$proc->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
echo $proc->transformToXML($doc);


?>
```